# How fill form data from Dropdown?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form on a page where users can save information, and a dropdown that pulls those saved files from the directory they saved them to. What I would like is when they go to that page, is that when they select the filename from the dropdown box, it places the name of the file in the input box "CodeDescription" field and the information on the file in the textarea "Code", however I am unsure how to go about parsing that. Below is my current code.

```
<input type="hidden" name="Action" value="EDIT" />
<input type="hidden" name="Selection"  id="Selection" value="-1">    
<div>Below is the list of your saved codes. To edit your codes, select it from the list.</div>
<select> 
<?php 
  $directory = $directory = 'users/' . $_SESSION['username'];
  $files = scandir( $directory ) ;
  foreach( $files as $file ) {
    if ( ! is_dir( $file ) ) {
      echo "<option>" . $file . "</option>";
    }
  }
  ?>
</select>
<h3>Saved Codes</h3>
<form method="post" action="/evo/avsaveprocess.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="Action" value="SAVE" />
  <input type="hidden" name="CodeId" id="CodeId" value="0" />
  <table width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td>Description:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="CodeDescription" size="40" maxlength="50" id="CodeName" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">Code:</td>
      <td>
        <textarea rows="10" style="width:99%" name="Code" id="CodeValue"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Or, conversely, I wouldn't mind if on select of the right file in the dropdown menu it simply displayed the output beneath the form fields.

edited to add javascript I was trying:

```
<script>

function CodeChange() {                            
        var filesContentJS = "$filesContents";
        if (index > 0) {
            document.getElementById("Selection").value = filesContentJS;
          } else {
            document.getElementById("Selection").value = "-1";
            document.getElementById("CodeId").value = "0";
            document.getElementById("CodeName").value = "";
            document.getElementById("CodeValue").value = "";
        }
    }

</script>
```

**updated javascript** This does not output any errors, however when I inspect element in Chrome it returns:

Warning:  file_get_contents(users/AddictionAddiction.txt) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/revo/public_html/evo/codesaveindex.php on line 141

which I'm not sure where to correct because there should be a / between AddictionAddiction.txt

Comment: create array of file content, while scrolling through files and generating <option> list. Then with JS input it into the fields depending on file selected

Comment: thank you cyadvert for your direction on where to get started with this. I'm not quite sure how to create the array of file content while scrolling through the files and generating the option list but am researching as a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of files contents:

```
<?php 
$directory = $directory = 'users/' . $_SESSION['username'];
$filesContents = Array();
$files = scandir( $directory ) ;

foreach( $files as $file )
{
if ( ! is_dir( $file ) )
{
$filesContents[$file] = file_get_contents($directory . $file);
echo "<option>" . $file . "</option>";
}
}
?>
```

Then make it Javascript array or JSON

```
<script>
var filesContentJS = <?=json_encode($filesContents) ?>;
</script>
```

An in the select use onChange="" function: get selected file from dropdown, scroll through filesContentJS to find its content and fill in the form with it

---

on another note: keep in mind, that if your files are large (have lots of code/text) - you might need to do this with AJAX...
When dropdown changes, do AJAX call to retrieve its info.

Comment: Thank you cyadvert for your help on this, it means the world. I had the array based off of tutorials I have almost written, so I appreciate the assist in confirming that though admittedly its with the javascript, getting the selected file from the dropdown and displaying it is the real part that i'm having trouble with.

Comment: Definitely keeping this in mind however these text files are thankfully really small

Comment: It does, partially, yes, though I am still trying to figure out the javascript to get the selected file from the dropdown and fill the form or just display it.

Comment: depending on JS library you may go different ways. For standard JS - .selectedIndex will help. For JQuery - .val(); Also, you will have to give your select a name <select name="[something]">

Comment: Thank you cyadvert I started a new question after marking this one answered specifically for help with the javascript unsure if I should have done that but will edit my post here with the javascript I was trying.

Comment: Thank you again for your help cyadvert am still working on it, I attempted it using jquery but am sure that my coding is wrong as I still cannot get the fields to populate on selection of the dropdown.

Comment: fixed that error with a , instead of a . However, with no errors, the information still does not display in the form fields