# Display results of Dropdown in Text fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Am hoping to ask another question here since the main one was answered on this thread:

[How fill form data from Dropdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28935075/how-fill-form-data-from-dropdown/28935594#28935594)

Though its abit of a continuation.

I am attempting to use javascript and an onChange() function to scroll through the files and then display them in the text input and text area fields on the form however I would appreciate any help in resolving my javascript. As it stands right now I can pull the file into the dropdown menu, but when I select one from the dropdown menu, nothing happens or populates on the form.

**edited to update** All errors seem to be resolved however nothing gets moved into the text boxes when selecting a file from the dropdown menu.

Javascript:

```
 <script>

function CodeChange() {
        var filesContentJS = "$filesContents"                            
        var index = filesContentJS.selectedIndex;
        var e = document.getElementById("CodeList");
        var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
            strUser = "0";
            integer document.getElementById("CodeId").value = 0;
            document.getElementById("CodeName").value = "";
            document.getElementById("CodeValue").value = "";
        }
</script>
```

**updated javascript**

And the form html and php itself for reference:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Action" value="EDIT" /><input type="hidden" name="Selection"  id="Selection" value="-1"><div>Below is the list of your saved codes. To edit your codes, select it from the list.</div>
<select size="1" name="CodeList" id="CodeList" onchange="CodeChange();"><option value="0">(Add New Code)</option>
<?php 
   $directory = $directory = 'users/' . $_SESSION['username'];
   $filesContents = Array();
   $files = scandir( $directory ) ;

   foreach( $files as $file )
 {
   if ( ! is_dir( $file ) )
 {
   $filesContents[$file] = file_get_contents($directory , $file);

  echo "<option>" . $file . "</option>";
 }
}
?>
</select>
    <h3>Saved Codes</h3>
    <form method="post" action="/evo/avsaveprocess.php">

     <input type="hidden" name="Action" value="SAVE" />
     <input type="hidden" name="CodeId" id="CodeId" value="0" />
     <table width="100%" border="0">
         <tr>
         <td>Description:</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="CodeDescription" size="40" maxlength="50" id="CodeName" value="" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td valign="top">Code:</td>
          <td>
            <textarea rows="10" style="width:99%" name="Code" id="CodeValue"></textarea>
               </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP array is still an array. You have to convert it to JS.
So, after you did all the `$filesContents[$file] = file_get_contents($directory , $file);`, then you need JS:

```
<script>
var filesContentJS = <?=json_encode($filesContents) ?>;
function CodeChange() {
var e = document.getElementById("CodeList"); // getting dropdown element
if (e.selectedIndex<=0) { // nothing selected - clean form
    document.getElementById("CodeId").value = 0;
    document.getElementById("CodeName").value = "";
    document.getElementById("CodeValue").value = "";
} else {
    var eStr = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value; // getting current element value
    // fill the form with data
    document.getElementById("CodeId").value = 0;// not sure what CodeId is - but this is the place to fill it
    document.getElementById("CodeName").value = eStr;
    document.getElementById("CodeValue").value = filesContentJS[eStr];
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
var e = document.getElementById("CodeList");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: Thank you moki, I edited my original post to show the changes I made. Am unsure if I put them in there right. It returned an uncaught syntax error with } else {, and says my CodeChange() is not defined. Not sure what I'm missing there.

Comment: Line after else  document.getElementById("Selection").value = "-1"; You do not need it. You have variable now strUser so use strUser = "-1"

Comment: updated it. Now the only error that comes back is uncaught typerror: cannot read undefined of undefined on this line.  var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

Comment: thanks moki that took away the error, however it still doesn't post anything to the form when the dropdown is selected. The only thing that I can see now is when I inspect the dropdown element is it tells me what I put up there in my edit: Warning which I think has to do with AddictionAddiction.txt needing to have a /between the directory and file name: file_get_contents(users/AddictionAddiction.txt) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/revo/public_html/evo/codesaveindex.php on line 141

Comment: Try with integer    document.getElementById("CodeId").value = 0;

Comment: fixed that error with a , instead of a . However, with no errors, the information still does not display in the form fields. Trying your suggestion now

Comment: I tried that and made the change in my original coding up top so you can see where I put it. returns syntaxerror; unexpected identifier

Comment: change that line to: 
strUser = 0

Comment: thanks for all your help, moki. changed and it still gives the unexpected identifier

Comment: noticed when I changed strUser = 0 and then removed integer on the other line I changed it removed the error but still not populating fields.